# How can I loop through a list of items and add these items to a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looping through several CSV files in a folder and checking the data types of each field in each file.  This works fine.  I'm trying to figure out how to add all these data types into a list and print the list.  So, I don't want to see just the data types of one file, I want to see the data types of all files.  Also, I want to capture the file name at the beginning of the list.  How can I do that?  Here is my sample code.

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
path = 'C:\\my_path\\*.csv'
for fname in glob.glob(path):
    print(fname)
    data = pd.read_csv(fname)
    for items in data.dtypes:
        print(items)

### something here...   


for item in L:
    print(item)
```

I would like the final outcome to look something like this:

```
ARMINDEX.CSV (file name)
  3624285               int64
  20181101              int64
  1.5                 float64

FHL_ARM.CSV
  20211120              int64
  1YRCMT               object
  3/1                  object

FNM_ARM.CSV
  3/1/2018             date 
  GNMD                 object
  2018110105:39:00     object
```

Comment: can you share the input csv?

Comment: What have you tried so far and what's the issue? You already identified all the ingredients necessary to achieve your goal, namely `fname` and `data.dtypes` (which acts like a dictionary if you use the `.items()` method).  All that's left is adding each of these into your desired `list`.  Also it's not clear whether your expected outcome structure is a `list` of `list`s or a `list` of `dict`s.

Comment: I just updated my question.  The 2 print statements do what I want.  I am just trying to understand how to create a list and append data sets to that list.  How can I do that?